# C# Xpath only returning first element

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I am using HTMLAgilityPack to read and load an XML file.  After the file is loaded, I want to insert the values from it into a database.

XML looks like this:

```
 <meeting>
       <jobname></jobname>
       <jobexperience></jobexperience>
 </meeting>
```

I'm trying to accomplish this using XPath statements within a foreach loop as seen here:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
//Add Data Columns here
dt.Columns.Add("JobName");
dt.Columns.Add("JobExperience");

// Create a string to read the XML tag "job"
string xPath_job = "//job";
string xPath_job_experience = "//jobexperience";


/* Use a ForEach loop to go through all 'meeting' tags and get the values
   from the 'JobName' and 'JobExperience' tags */  

foreach (HtmlNode planned_meeting in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//meeting"))
{
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

    dr["JobName"] = planned_meeting.SelectSingleNode(xPath_job).InnerText;

    dr["JobName"] = planned_meeting.SelectSingleNode(xPath_job_experience).InnerText;

    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

}
```

So the problem is that even though the foreach loop is going through every 'meeting' tag, it's getting the values from only the first 'meeting' tag.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think your xpath queries should just be `jobname` and `jobexperience`, without the slashes.

Comment: Yup xPath_* variables mustn't have the slashes.

Comment: See [this handy page](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) for an XPath cheat-sheet.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Bravo! Answered in 1 line.

Comment: I was typing up a proper answer, but zx485 beat me to it.  I like his explanation better than what I had anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So the problem is that even though the foreach loop is going through every 'meeting' tag, it's getting the values from only the first 'meeting' tag.

Yes, that's what the code does. The [XPath operator `//`](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) selects *all* the elements in the whole document, e.g. `//job` select *all* `job` elements in the whole document.

So in your foreach loop you select all `meeting` elements in the whole document with

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//meeting"))
```

and then - in the loop - you select all `//job` and all `//jobexperience` elements in the whole document with

```
string xPath_job = "//job";
string xPath_job_experience = "//jobexperience";
```

So you select the first element of *all* elements - over and over again... Hence the impression that you only get the first element.

---

So change the code in a way that the children of the *current* `meeting` element get selected (by removing the `//` operator):

```
string xPath_job            = "job";
string xPath_job_experience = "jobexperience";
```